# Bootstrap Maxlength with dynamically generated text boxes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, textarea, maxlength

Hope anyone can help.

I am using [Bootstap Maxlength](http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/) on textareas that are being dynamically generated by cloning from a template. The template counter works perfectly (awesome plugin by the way!!!) because it is natively in the html. But when it creates a clone, the elements are generated in the DOM dynamically and so the plugin doesn't work because, I'm thinking, it doesn't recognize the new elements as existing. Am not very familiar with jquery, so wouldn't really know how to create a function to get around this.

Jquery's `.on` function doesn't seem to work. I tried this by calling it at the bottom of the page it's on:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $("textarea").characterCounter({
        limit: 120
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure that's not sematically correct, but I don't have a clue how else to do it. If anyone has any answers, I'd be forever in your debt :)

Thanks!

Comment: That code is just running once, wnen the document is ready, and that runs just one time, you need to call characterCounter() every time you add a new texbox, there is no event that reports you the create event or element added to the DOM.

Comment: The problem is that the textarea is inside another element that is being cloned already. The textarea is dynamically generated by default by being wrapped in the container. Why wouldn't the maxlength be as well? So I need to call it uniquely inside the clone?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand why. It isn't a static html element while textarea is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are rite ! Call the function after the elements are generated in the DOM dynamically

While generating textbox do the following

Step 1 : Genereate textbox by cloning, then

Step 2 : Call the Function `$("textarea").characterCounter({limit: 120});`

For Example:

```
function Clone(){
GenerateTextBoxes();
$("textarea").characterCounter({limit: 120});
}
```